# Pre image of product of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $f$ be a surjective homomorphism from $R$ to $S$. How pre image of product of ideal $f^{-1}(I_1...I_n)$and product of pre images  of ideals $f^{-1}(I_1)...f^{-1}(I_n)$ are related. I know they need not be equal,  is any of the containment holds?

Comment: I think $f^{-1}(I_1...I_n) $ contains $f^{-1}(I_1)...f^{-1}(I_n)$ but I am having hard time proving it , so it makes me wonder if at all this is true

Comment: Yes, $f^{-1}(I_1)\ldots f^{-1}(I_n) \subset f^{-1}(I_1\ldots I_n)$, that’s “just” symbol manipulation.

Comment: @Mindlack actually I was working on some other problem I worked for long time on that,  I later found all my works are valid only if this property hold (I used it in middle of somewhere) , it makes me nervous . Thanks a lot , If you are interested in adding this comment as answer I will accept that

Comment: What's preimage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let, for each $1 \leq k \leq n$, $a_k \in f^{-1}(I_k)$. Then $f(a_1\ldots a_n)=f(a_1)\ldots f(a_n) \in I_1 \ldots I_n$ so that $a_1 \ldots a_n \in f^{-1}(I_1 \ldots I_n)$, therefore $f^{-1}(I_1) \ldots f^{-1}(I_n) \subset f^{-1}(I_1 \ldots I_n)$.